# Rasa chatbot works in 1.10 version but fails in Rasa 2.2 version?

Tags: upgrade, chatbot, rasa-nlu

I planned to upgrade my Rasa bots for 2.x version. After upgrade bot doesn't work any more.

Here is how it works in 1.10, I choose wrong answer and bot says "wrong asnwer" and moves to question 2.

```
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Received user message '/vaara_vastaus01' with intent '{'name': 'vaara_vastaus01', 'confidence': 1.0}' and entities '[]'
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Logged UserUtterance - tracker now has 8 events.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - Current tracker state [None, {}, {'prev_action_listen': 1.0, 'intent_aloita': 1.0}, {'prev_utter_ask_kysymys01': 1.0, 'intent_aloita': 1.0}, {'intent_vaara_vastaus01': 1.0, 'prev_action_listen': 1.0}]
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - There is no memorised next action
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.fallback  - NLU confidence threshold met, confidence of fallback action set to core threshold (0.3).
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Predicted next action using policy_1_TEDPolicy
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Predicted next action 'utter_vaara_vastaus01' with confidence 0.88.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Action 'utter_vaara_vastaus01' ended with events '[BotUttered('Answer is wrong', {"elements": null, "quick_replies": null, "buttons": null, "attachment": null, "image": null, "custom": null}, {}, 1621415523.6351407)]'.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - Current tracker state [{}, {'prev_action_listen': 1.0, 'intent_aloita': 1.0}, {'prev_utter_ask_kysymys01': 1.0, 'intent_aloita': 1.0}, {'intent_vaara_vastaus01': 1.0, 'prev_action_listen': 1.0}, {'intent_vaara_vastaus01': 1.0, 'prev_utter_vaara_vastaus01': 1.0}]
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - There is no memorised next action
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.mapping_policy  - There is no mapped action for the predicted intent, 'vaara_vastaus01'.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.fallback  - NLU confidence threshold met, confidence of fallback action set to core threshold (0.3).
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Predicted next action using policy_1_TEDPolicy
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Predicted next action 'utter_ask_kysymys02' with confidence 0.85.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Action 'utter_ask_kysymys02' ended with events '[BotUttered('Question 2/20  Which of the following numbers is different from the others?', {"elements": null, "quick_replies": null, "buttons": [{"payload": "/vaara_vastaus02", "title": "0,285"}, {"payload": "/oikea_vastaus02", "title": "285/100"}, {"payload": "/vaara_vastaus02", "title": "28,5%"}], "attachment": null, "image": null, "custom": null}, {}, 1621415523.6392612)]'.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - Current tracker state [{'prev_action_listen': 1.0, 'intent_aloita': 1.0}, {'prev_utter_ask_kysymys01': 1.0, 'intent_aloita': 1.0}, {'intent_vaara_vastaus01': 1.0, 'prev_action_listen': 1.0}, {'intent_vaara_vastaus01': 1.0, 'prev_utter_vaara_vastaus01': 1.0}, {'intent_vaara_vastaus01': 1.0, 'prev_utter_ask_kysymys02': 1.0}]
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - There is no memorised next action
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.mapping_policy  - There is no mapped action for the predicted intent, 'vaara_vastaus01'.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.fallback  - NLU confidence threshold met, confidence of fallback action set to core threshold (0.3).
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Predicted next action using policy_1_TEDPolicy
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Predicted next action 'action_listen' with confidence 0.98.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Action 'action_listen' ended with events '[]'.
2021-05-19 09:12:03 DEBUG    rasa.core.lock_store  - Deleted lock for conversation '01880209ad0e42618fe3299cdd2083b1'.
Answer is wrong
? Question 2/20  Which of the following numbers is different from the others?  (Use arrow keys)
 » 1: 0,285 (/vaara_vastaus02)
   2: 285/100 (/oikea_vastaus02)
   3: 28,5% (/vaara_vastaus02)
   Type out your own message...
```

But in 2.2 it stops after given wrong answer to question 1. Also I get following error

> 2021-05-19 09:55:34 WARNING  rasa.utils.common  - Failed to write global config. Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.config'. Skipping.

```
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Received user message '/vaara_vastaus01' with intent '{'name': 'vaara_vastaus01', 'confidence': 1.0}' and entities '[]'
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Logged UserUtterance - tracker now has 9 events.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - Current tracker state:
[state 1] user intent: aloita | previous action name: action_listen
[state 2] user intent: aloita | previous action name: utter_ask_kysymys01
[state 3] user intent: vaara_vastaus01 | previous action name: action_listen
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - There is no memorised next action
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.rule_policy  - Current tracker state:
[state 1] user intent: aloita | previous action name: action_listen
[state 2] user intent: aloita | previous action name: utter_ask_kysymys01
[state 3] user text: /vaara_vastaus01 | previous action name: action_listen
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.rule_policy  - There is no applicable rule.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.rule_policy  - Current tracker state:
[state 1] user intent: aloita | previous action name: action_listen
[state 2] user intent: aloita | previous action name: utter_ask_kysymys01
[state 3] user intent: vaara_vastaus01 | previous action name: action_listen
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.rule_policy  - There is no applicable rule.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Made prediction using user intent.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Added `DefinePrevUserUtteredFeaturization(False)` event.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Predicted next action using policy_2_RulePolicy.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Predicted next action 'action_default_fallback' with confidence 0.30.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Policy prediction ended with events '[<rasa.shared.core.events.DefinePrevUserUtteredFeaturization object at 0x7fb23a686ad0>]'.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Action 'action_default_fallback' ended with events '[<rasa.shared.core.events.UserUtteranceReverted object at 0x7fb23911e850>]'.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - Current tracker state:
[state 1] user intent: aloita | previous action name: action_listen
[state 2] user intent: aloita | previous action name: utter_ask_kysymys01
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.memoization  - There is a memorised next action 'action_listen'
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.rule_policy  - Current tracker state:
[state 1] user intent: aloita | previous action name: action_listen
[state 2] user intent: aloita | previous action name: utter_ask_kysymys01
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.rule_policy  - There is no applicable rule.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - Predicted next action using policy_0_MemoizationPolicy.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Predicted next action 'action_listen' with confidence 1.00.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Policy prediction ended with events '[]'.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.processor  - Action 'action_listen' ended with events '[]'.
2021-05-19 09:11:56 DEBUG    rasa.core.lock_store  - Deleted lock for conversation '57c517c99766474f9d7a6786629e2454'.
Your input ->
```

Here is my config file for 1.1

```
# Configuration for Rasa NLU.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/
language: en
pipeline:
  - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
  - name: RegexFeaturizer
  - name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
    analyzer: "char_wb"
    min_ngram: 1
    max_ngram: 4
  - name: DIETClassifier
    epochs: 100
  - name: EntitySynonymMapper
  - name: ResponseSelector
    epochs: 100

# Configuration for Rasa Core.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/
policies:
  - name: MemoizationPolicy
  - name: TEDPolicy
    max_history: 5
    epochs: 100
  - name: MappingPolicy
  - name: "FallbackPolicy"
    nlu_threshold: 0.5
    core_threshold: 0.3
    fallback_action_name: "action_default_fallback"
```

and here for 2.2

```
# Configuration for Rasa NLU.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/
language: en

pipeline:
# # No configuration for the NLU pipeline was provided. The following default pipeline was used to train your model.
# # If you'd like to customize it, uncomment and adjust the pipeline.
# # See https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/tuning-your-model for more information.
   - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
   - name: RegexFeaturizer
   - name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
   - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
   - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
     analyzer: "char_wb"
     min_ngram: 1
     max_ngram: 4
   - name: DIETClassifier
     epochs: 100
   - name: EntitySynonymMapper
   - name: ResponseSelector
     epochs: 100
   - name: FallbackClassifier
     threshold: 0.3
     ambiguity_threshold: 0.1

# Configuration for Rasa Core.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/
policies:
# # No configuration for policies was provided. The following default policies were used to train your model.
# # If you'd like to customize them, uncomment and adjust the policies.
# # See https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/policies for more information.
   - name: MemoizationPolicy
   - name: TEDPolicy
     max_history: 5
     epochs: 100
   - name: RulePolicy
```

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from Rasa forum that worked, here it is

First I changed epochs to 300, that helped and bot continued questions, but they were in wrong order. So next I reverted epochs to 100 and changed MemoizationPolicy with AugmentedMemoizationPolicy and bot failed in beginning, again. Then I changed epochs to 300 and kept AugmentedMemoizationPolicy and now bot works like before in 1.10.